# Parsing JSON data in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes

Obviously, this question is a bit Rails beginner question, however it is vital for me.

I'm trying to get multiple variables (more than a single id, parameters like **username**,**versionNo**), nothing specific. What I'm trying to understand is, I'm writing the backend of an mobile application, when the client sends me JSON variables with post, in where I should try to serialize it, in order to use it for operations such as database querying. I'm assuming that it will be on controller, but still just want to be sure.

Also within pre-defined 7 methods I've assumed that **index** method would be the most suitable function to do operations like database querying and etc.Since there are multiple parameters, I didn't think **show** operation would be feasible. But again there are tons of Rails experts in here.

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to CRUD, POST request should be equal to create method in your controller.
Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions